# What would be a standard indicator for a selection set to default?

Tags: gui-design, settings, default

I have a table with different user options.

These options are either coming from a base template (Standard), a customized base template (Custom), or a customized base template that has not yet been published/finalized (Draft).

[image]

From these options, the user can select one to set as a default using an option from the ellipsis menu under each row. This default will then be used as the default rate for them.

What is the best way to indicate that this rate is their default? A star icon next to the rate name? A left border? Any other ideas?

Note that there can only be one default rate.

Comment: Any reason you can't just use the word "default"?

Comment: @musefan you can, but I wanted to see if there were also other alternatives. Even though we would only have one default, there are many other statuses - Custom, Standard, and Draft. For each of those, there could be multiples. So instead of "default" being another status type that can get buried within other status types, I thought that maybe it can be symbolized with an icon instead.

Comment: What job is the default rate doing? Is the user going to compare other values to it in this view, or in another context?

Comment: @lzquierdo Yes, the user will need to compare (and sort) different values within this table.

Answer (score 2):

A star can mean many things, but text is simple and removes any confusion. Just use a text label. At a broader level, text is a bunch of symbols anyway.

[image]